# Help solving an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

This is an example in my book.  It is for the following system:

\begin{align*}
x'&=y+x(1-x^2-y^2)\\
y'&=-x+y(1-x^2-y^2)
\end{align*}

So using polar coordinates we get the following system
\begin{align*}
r'&=r(1-r^2)\\
\theta'&=-1,
\end{align*}
and the solutions are 
$$r(t)=(1+ce^{-2t})^{\frac{-1}{2}}, \,\,\,\,\,\,\theta(t)=-(t-\alpha).$$

So my question is how did they solve $r'$.  It's been a while since I've take differential equations and I need help how to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So $r'=r(1-r^2)$ which means 
$$\int\frac{dr}{r(1-r^2)}=\int dt$$
Using partial fraction on LHS, we obtain,
$$\int \frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{2(r+1)}-\frac{1}{2(r-1)} dr = t+c$$
$$\ln r - \frac{1}{2}\ln(r+1)- \frac{1}{2}\ln(r-1)=t+c$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-1}}\right)=t+c$$
$$\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-1}}=Ae^t$$
where $A=e^c$
$$\frac{r^2}{{r^2-1}}=Be^{2t}$$
where $B=A^2$
$$1-\frac{1}{r^2}=Be^{-2t}$$

so $$r =(1-Be^{-2t})^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$